# Why won't lightbox trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I have a fancybox lightbox implemented [on this site](http://www.marathonmarketingservices.com/) and it won't open and I can't figure out why.

For reference, it's working on this site:  http://triathlon.joomlatest01.mms-dev.com/

Once you click either "Learn More" or "Don't show this again", it will set a cookie and won't show up again (unless you clear your cookies).

I added all the same code (listed below) to both sites, so dont know why it's not working.

```
<!-- Add fancyBox Lightbox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function setCookie() {
document.cookie="lightboxcookie=lightboxseen; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2020 12:00:00 UTC";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";

}

function checkCookie() {
 var thecookie=getCookie("lightboxcookie");
    if (thecookie != "") {
        } else {
            <!--Show Lightbox-->
            jQuery.noConflict()(function ($) { 
                $(document).ready(function() { 
                                        $(".lightbox").fancybox({
                            helpers : {
                                                       overlay : {
                                                          closeClick: false,
                                                          css : {
                                                         'background' : 'rgba(0, 45, 92, 0.80)'
                                                          }
                                                       }
                                                    }
                    });
                    $(".lightbox").eq(0).trigger('click');

                });
            });
    }
}
</script>

<body onload="checkCookie()">

<style>

div#lightbox {
background: #fff;
opacity: 1 !important;
height: 200px;
text-align: center;
}
div#lightbox h1{
font-size: 20px;
}

a.lightbox {
display: inline-block;
max-width: 200px;
background: #002D5C;
color: white;
border-radius: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 5px 20px;
}
a.lightbox_learnmore {
height: 40px;
font-size: 28px;
padding-top: 1px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
a.lightbox_dontshow {
height: 30px;
font-size: 12px;
padding-top: 8px;
}
a.lightbox_dontshow {
background: #ddd;
color: gray;
}
a.lightbox_learnmore:hover {
background: #1366a0;
}
a.lightbox_dontshow:hover {
background: #bbb;
color: white;
}
a.fancybox-close {
display: none;
}
.fancybox-skin {
background: #ffffff;
}
div#lightbox p{
max-width: 500px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
.fancybox-inner {
width: 650px !important;
height: 500px !important;
}
@media (min-width: 10px) and (max-width:767px) {
    .fancybox-inner {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    }   
    .fancybox-wrap {
    top: 25px !important;   
    }
    .fancybox-skin {
    height: 700px !important;   
    }
    .fancybox-inner {
    height: 700px !important;   
    }
}
</style>

<a style="display: none;" class="lightbox" href="#lightbox">Lightbox</a>

<div style="display:none"><div id="lightbox"><h1><img src="http://ww2.joomlatest01.mms-dev.com/images/mds_logo.png" width=200/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="http://ww2.joomlatest01.mms-dev.com/images/isnow.png" width=80 /> &nbsp;<img src="http://ww2.joomlatest01.mms-dev.com/images/Workwave_Logo_250.png" /></h1>
<br/>
<p>We’ve changed our name from Marathon Data Systems to WorkWave! The Marathon Data Systems brand has been a mainstay in field service management software for over 30 years.   We’re doing this now, because we feel the time is right to unify our brand and messaging to more accurately reflect how our product offerings connect every aspect of our your business, providing an unprecedented level of insight into your office and field operations enabling you to truly delight your clients and supercharge your business performance.</p>
<p> 
Our goal is to make this transition as easy as possible with little to no impact for our customers. For frequently asked questions regarding our change to WorkWave and how it may affect you, please click “learn more” for additional info.
  </p>
<a class="lightbox lightbox_learnmore" href="" onclick="setCookie()">Learn More</a><br/><a class="lightbox lightbox_dontshow" href="" onclick="setCookie()">Don't show this again</a>
</div></div>
```

Comment: I get a bunch of errors on your page, including a 404 for `jquery-2.1.1.js`. Check your browser console for problems.

Comment: thanks!  i added the google URL for jquery and that seemed to fix it.